# How to read this ACF & PACF plots?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I am performing an interrupted time series analysis. I plotted the data and then checked for autocorrelation using ACF and PACF.

[image: Here is the ACF on LHS and PACF on RHS]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
acf(residuals(model_ols), main="ACF") 
acf(residuals(model_ols), type = "partial", main="PACF")
```

How do make sense of this plot now? Can someone tell me what should be the next step?

Comment: i am using the following code: 
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(residuals(model_ols), main="ACF")
acf(residuals(model_ols), type = "partial", main="PACF")...There are 16 observations . I hope lag.max is fine.

Comment: I would judge there's basically nothing going on here.  The fact that PACF(2) (and ACF(4) is marginally beyond the 95% confidence interval is compensated by the fact that you're looking at about 25 comparisons ...

Comment: @BenBolker when I use p=2 and then check for model improvement for p=3 or 4 through anova(model_p2,model_p3), it shows very significant p-value.
What can I do now??